# In java, Date() method returns a value. but I am confused in that

Tags: java, date

I used `Date()` for getting the date of my birthday, but it was returned the mismatch of the month. My birthday is 04-March-87. so i gave an input as,

```
Date birthDay= new Date(87,03,04,8,30,00);
```

But it returns correct year, day and time. But month was problem. It displays April month.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: can you give bit brief about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Months are set from 0 to 11, January =0, February = 1, ..., December = 11.

So, for April do this:

```
Date birthDate = new Date(87,02,04,8,30,00); //March = 2
```

Hope this helps;

**EDIT**

The `Date` class with this constructor `public Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min)` is deprecated (i.e. it has been declared `@Deprecated`).

Rather do this.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar.set(1987, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0);
Date birthDate = calendar.getTime();
```

(It will return the same thing as what you asked for)

Answer (score 5):

The month in the [`Date`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class starts with 0 for January, so March is 2, not 3.

Also, the [`Date(int, int, int, int, int, int)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) constructor is deprecated, so you should consider using the [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class instead.

Finally, be careful with leading zeros in Java - they represent octal constants. The number `09` would not do what you expect.